# Regular expression building: Comment delimited strings

Tags: regular-expressions, finite-automata

I'm attempting to build a regular expression that will accept only strings of the form:

```
Begins with: /#

Ends with: #/

Contains the following in between /# and #/: 
Any combination of {a, b, /, #} but not the combination #/
```

Bascially, a regular expression that determines whether a string is appropriately comment delimited.  I've tried many expressions, but can't find anything that quite works.  I'm not sure how to allow all other combinations of a,b,/,# but disallow #/.  Any help putting me on the right track would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let me write $c$ for $/$ and $d$ for $\#$ to increase readability. Let
$A = \{a, b, c, d\}$. The language you want can be expressed by the extended regular expression $cd(A^* - A^*dcA^*)dc$.

This language is accepted by the following DFA (initial state $1$, unique final state $5$)
\begin{array}
  &&&\mid &1 &2 &3 &4 &5 \\   
\hline 
&a,b &\mid &- &- &3 &3 &-  \\
&\ c &\mid &2 &- &3 &5 &-  \\
&\ d &\mid &- &3 &4 &4 &-
\end{array}
The transitions are
$\ \xrightarrow{} 1 \xrightarrow{c} 2 \xrightarrow{d} 3 \xrightarrow{d} 4 \xrightarrow{c} 5 \xrightarrow{}$, $\quad 4 \xrightarrow{a,b} 3$, $\quad 3 \xrightarrow{a,b,c} 3$, $\quad 4 \xrightarrow{d} 4$.
One can now convert this automaton to the regular expression 
$$cd\bigl(a+b+c+dd^*(a+b)\bigr)^*d^*dc$$
Coming back to the original notation, we get finally 
$$/\#\bigl(a+b+/+\#\#^*(a+b)\bigr)^*\#^*\#/$$